# How to send image and fields to form via POST

Tags: iphone, forms, multipartform-data

I've a form like this:

```
<form id="form" action="/post" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
    <input type="file" name="image" /> 
    <input type="text" name="name1" /> 
    <input type="text" name="name2" /> 
    <textarea name="text"></textarea> 
    <input type="text" name="name3" />  
</form>
```

And I've a method like this:

```
- (void)sendFields {

UIImage *tempImage = imageViewToPost.image;

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://url/post/"]];


NSString *boundary = @"------------0xKhTmLbOuNdArY";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];



NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];


[body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\"; filename=\"photo.png\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(tempImage, 90)]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];

[body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"name1\"\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[nameToPost dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"name2\"\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[priceToPost dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"text\"\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[commentToPost dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"name3\"\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[coordsToPost dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
[request setHTTPBody:body];

NSError *error;
NSURLResponse *response;
NSData *result = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

NSString *aStr = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:result encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] autorelease];

NSLog(@"Result: %@", aStr);

[request release];    

}
```

It doesn't work. What's wrong here?

Thanks guys.

Comment: "It doesn't work" is kind of broad. An actual description of how it doesn't work would be nice. Does the app crash? Is the wrong result returned? If so, are you confirming that the request body is correct?

Comment: Application doesn't crash. Sorry, I mean the data was not sent, and the form return the same page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend looking at the ASIHTTPRequest library. I have had success posting images and data with it. It's very simple to use and to get setup. Plus, is has a very nice asynchronous model built in.

[ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use)

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to share some code that worked for me.

```
- (void)allSet {
    //creating the url request:
    NSURL *cgiUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mysite.com/upload.php"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *postRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:cgiUrl];

    NSString *stringBoundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"0194784892923"];
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",stringBoundary];
    [postRequest addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.thePicture.photo, 0.5);

    //setting up the body:
    NSMutableData *postBody = [NSMutableData data];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"category\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"photos"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"format\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"JSON"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"title\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:thePicture.title] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"description\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:thePicture.description] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"latitude\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", [thePicture.latitude floatValue]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"longitude\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", [thePicture.longitude floatValue]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"photo\"; filename=\"%@.jpg\"\r\n", thePicture.title] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    //adding header information:
    [postRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [postRequest setHTTPBody:postBody];

    // create the connection with the request
    // and start loading the data
    theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:postRequest delegate:self];
    [theConnection start];

    if (theConnection) {
        // Create the NSMutableData that will hold
        // the received data
        // receivedData is declared as a method instance elsewhere
        receivedData=[[NSMutableData data] retain];
    } else {
        // inform the user that the download could not be made
    }   
}
```

Tough, I had problems with the way I was setting the boundaries and separators @"\r\n--%@--\r\n" . Try my code, maybe I can solve your problems.

Answer (score 0):

i used this code in my App and it works perfectly help ...

```
//create request
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

//Set Params
[request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];
[request setTimeoutInterval:60];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

//Create boundary, it can be anything
NSString *boundary = @"------VohpleBoundary4QuqLuM1cE5lMwCy";

// set Content-Type in HTTP header
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
[request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

// post body
NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

//Populate a dictionary with all the regular values you would like to send.
NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

[parameters setValue:param1 forKey:@"param1-name"];

[parameters setValue:param2 forKey:@"param2-name"];

[parameters setValue:param3 forKey:@"param3-name"];


// add params (all params are strings)
for (NSString *param in parameters) {
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n", param] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\r\n", [parameters objectForKey:param]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}

NSString *FileParamConstant = @"imageParamName";

NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageObject, 1);

//Assuming data is not nil we add this to the multipart form
if (imageData)
{
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"; filename=\"image.jpg\"\r\n", FileParamConstant] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Type:image/jpeg\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:imageData];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}

//Close off the request with the boundary
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

// setting the body of the post to the request
[request setHTTPBody:body];

// set URL
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:baseUrl]];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {

                           NSHTTPURLResponse* httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;

                           if ([httpResponse statusCode] == 200) {

                               NSLog(@"success");
                           }

                       }];
```